# uncheck all other checkboxes when decline is clicked and uncheck decline if other checkbox is checked

Tags: jsf

I am displaying a list of string values from the bean as checkboxes in jsf as below

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value = "#{bean.selectedcountries}">
<f:selectitems value = "#{bean.countries}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

the selected countries list will contain the user selected values before from database. and the countries list will contain the list of options for the user to choose from while editing data.

Now, in the countries list a value is there as Decline, so if user select decline all other checked options should be unchecked automatically and if the decline option checked if user is trying to select any other checkbox Decline option should be unchecked automatically.

I am pretty new to JSF . How to achieve this.

Comment: Start with learning about `f:ajax`... (unless you want to do it pure client-side with several risks involved)

Comment: In the setter of `selectedcountries` you can compare new and old value and set the bean value according your requirements. Please also read [ask] and try to provide [mcve] regarding specific problems related to own actual attempts.